# Xor Bytes in Java

Tags: java, casting, xor

Java has no support for bit-wise operations on bytes.  I would like to xor two bytes like so:

```
xoredByte = byte1 ^ byte2;
```

In java this would have to be done as:

```
xoredByte = (byte) (byte1 ^ byte2);
```

Which compiles to:

```
xoredByte = (byte) ((int)byte1 ^ (int)byte2);
```

Does this work in all cases?  What I mean is, are these equivalent statements?

If not, what would the code be to perform this operation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, both statements are equivalent.  When working with binary operators in general, including `^`, Java applies "binary numeric promotion" to both operands to ensure that they are both at least `int` values.  [Section 5.6.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) covers this:

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> - If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
> - Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> - Otherwise, **both operands are converted to type int**.

(emphasis mine)

and

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands of certain operators:
>
> - The multiplicative operators *, /, and % (§15.17)
> - The addition and subtraction operators for numeric types + and - (§15.18.2)
> - The numerical comparison operators <, <=, >, and >= (§15.20.1)
> - The numerical equality operators == and != (§15.21.1)
> - **The integer bitwise operators &, ^, and |** (§15.22.1)
> - In certain cases, the conditional operator ? : (§15.25)

(emphasis mine)

Whether you apply the `(int)` casts or not, `byte1` and `byte2` will both be promoted to `int` before the operation.  That is also why the cast back to `(byte)` is necessary.

Comment: Might be nice to include that this is because the standard is to use 32-bit ALUs, rather than "just because". :)

Comment: why operands smaller than int get promoted to int ? its somehow related to a computer word ?

Comment: @voipp your question is just answered in the comment before yours.

Answer (score 7):

What happens is that when the value is cast from `byte` to `int`, 24 new bits are inserted in front of the 8 bits of a byte.  These bits could be all 0's or all 1's (since `byte` is a signed type).  The result of `^` could therefore have 24 zeroes or 24 ones as the most significant bits.  However, when the result is cast back to `byte`, those 24 bits are thrown away, no matter what they are; and since `^` is done on a bit-by-bit basis, the low-order 8 bits are the same as they would be if there were an `^` operation on bytes--the upper 24 bits don't have any effect on the lower 8.